# Measuring JIT time of a .NET application

Tags: .net, jit, ngen

I'm aware that you can use [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx) to make native pre-compiled images of your .NET application.

But how do you measure how much time your application has spent in JIT? I'd like to know how much time is to be saved before doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NET6.0 you can use the `System.Runtime.JitInfo` static class to get an overview:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.jitinfo?view=net-6.0

Example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Time: {JitInfo.GetCompilationTime(false)}");
Console.WriteLine($"ILBytes: {JitInfo.GetCompiledILBytes(false)}");
Console.WriteLine($"MethodCount: {JitInfo.GetCompiledMethodCount(false)}");
```

Passing in `true` to these methods returns values for the current thread (instead of global).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no "Absolute time in JIT" statistic that you will be able to get.  The CLR does expose a "% Time in Jit" performance counter that it updates periodically, but it is only as accurate as it chooses to sample.

You can access this performance counter pretty easily through the Windows Performance Monitor tool or through tools like RedGate's ANTS Profiler--which is how I was first exposed to it.  If you need programmatic access to it, you could use WMI or the .NET PerformanceCounter class.

Comment: That doesn't look like a very helpful counter. It barely moves at all when a lot of JITing is happening, but it spikes to 100% at random times when no additional bytes are being JIT-ed. (Like re-opening a closed window)

Comment: That is not my experience.  It has been very coarse grained and swung around a lot based on their sampling patterns, but it has always corresponded with periods including JIT compilation for me.

Comment: It does seem to roughly correlate to those times. But this doesn't tell me how much I stand to gain by using NGen.

Answer (score 3):

[This article about measuring JIT impact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2010/04/27/ngen-measuring-warm-startup-performance-with-xperf.aspx) was very helpful. Basically you would use NGen for warm startup scenarios. Cold startup times are usually dominated by loading the DLLs into memory. JIT compilation has much more impact on warm startup.

It's kind of fuzzy about how to install xperf: basically you want to download the [Windows 7 .NET 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B) and make sure to select the Performance Toolkit. Then open a VS 2010 command prompt as administrator, change to the directory of the program you want to profile and follow the commands in the article.

The basic gist of it is that with an xperf capture you can then drill down into your process and see how much time was spent in clrjit.dll. In my case 30% of CPU time was spent there on warm startup.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, or agree with your conclusion. If you NGen'ed your assembly then the images to be loaded from disk are much larger (which may slow cold startup time). If you didn't NGen your assembly, the images are smaller, but JIT kicks in, which also takes time. If you NGen, there is no JIT (unless you load assemblies that are not NGen'ed already).

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing here. NGen helps on warm startups and not cold.