# WCF service slow call depending on caller

Tags: c#, wcf

I have set up a local WCF service, self hosted in a console application using `NetNamedPipeBinding` for client access.

To make calls to the service I reference a `library.dll` where I have the following method:

```cs
public static string GetLevel(Point p)
{   
    ChannelFactory<IService> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PTS_Service"));
    IService pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    string result = pipeProxy.GetLevel(p);
    ((IClientChannel)pipeProxy).Close();
    pipeFactory.Close();
}
```

The `GetLevel()` command returns a string from a list stored in the service, based on the Z coordinate of Point(X,Y,Z) p.

This works and gives speeds of 8ms total if the method is called from the above console app.

However when the same method from the `library.dll` is called from another `app.exe` or `plugin.dll` (loaded by an external program) the times increase drastically. I've stop watched the above 5 lines of code:

- consoleHost.exe : 0 - 3 - 6 - 7 - 8
- app.exe : 89 - 155 - 248 - 259 - 271
- plugin.dll : 439 - 723 - 1210 - 1229 - 1245

Shouldn't the times be the same, not dependent on who makes the call to `library.dll`?

**EDIT**

Since I've cancelled out all methods to just retrieving a string from a running service, I believe the problem lies in the first creation run of the channelFactory, all subsequent calls in the same app/plugin run are equal in time.

I understand the first call is slower, but as I see this is around 30ms in a new app and around 900ms in my plugins, I believe there is another thing causing this.

I have found a question with similar delays:
[First WCF connection made in new AppDomain is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149651/first-wcf-connection-made-in-new-appdomain-is-very-slow) to which the solution was to set `LoaderOptimizationAttribute` to `MultiDomain`. Could it be possible everytime the plugin runs it has to JIT-compile instead of use native code?

I tried adding this code above main in `consoleHost.exe` but see no gain in the plugin run time. Could this be because of the external program in between and is there a way around this? Say could my plugin create a new Appdomain whenever it wants to access the service and call from within this new Appdomain the above method from my `library.dll` or does this make no sense?

**EDIT2**

I recorded the time spent in JIT compiling with a profiling program as suggested in the comments, this gives 700ms for JIT compiling and total execution time of 800ms for the plugin.

I used ngen to precompile the library.dll to create a native image .ni.dll. I see in process explorer that this image is loaded by the external program, though there is no time gain in the plugin? As I understand there shouldn't be a reason the plugin would still JIT compile or am I doing something wrong?

I also noticed when debugging in VS that the console & app only do some loading of assemblies, the plugin loads and unloads everytime it creates or modifies a plugin instance. I believe this is the way plugins work and should not explain the difference in first execution time?

Comment: Could it be that the call into the dll is the first call into the dll? In that case the loading of the dll and its dependencies could be part of the time it takes for the first call

Comment: The dll is accessed before (non service method) so should be loaded allready? Furthermore why would this not be so slow for the app?

Comment: Just in time compilation doesn't work that way. It only compiles the finctions that are called, just before they're called. So not per assembly. Put the timing around the code that you showed INSIDE the dll. To measure more accurately.

Comment: Ok I see. How do I prevent JIT compilation in the plugin then? Timings indeed are larger for every line/function called, like described in the referenced link.

Comment: I see two options (if this is actually the problem): 1: at the start of the program call all vital functions once or 2: use NGen.exe to precompile code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator

Comment: Note that it is yet unclear to me if JIT Compilation is the actual problem. A lot depends on how you are measuring.

Comment: As every new started app.exe has a first call total of 30ms, isn't all code already precompiled somewhere but unaccessible from within the plugin? I added a new StopWatch sw before the first line and after every next line I wrote to a logfile sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(). In the last testings I only read the sw after the 5th line.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without seeing the actual code. Code is precompiled per function, not per assembly,  not per class.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768727/measuring-jit-time-of-a-net-application for reference to answers and articles that might help you to measure and implement

Answer (score 0):

The communication should not depend on a caller, but the way the calls are done.

The most time expensive operation is creating a Channel.
Should the Proxy once created, then every next call will be done with a an average similar speed. (Of cause if the callers are using the service from the same place: same Machine in the Network. In your case should be the same, while in your case you use the localhost)

Some performance increase can be also archived by service configuration (SingleInstance should be faster than PerCall).

Another point to pay attention is to exam the possible locks in your service method. It can happen than some service clients are waiting for a call, while the service is busy.

if the service call is not an async one, try to make it async and use it.

Comment: I've added the SingleInstance, with perhaps a slight improvement in performance. However, I started looking in to services to keep a central access to multiple lists or even SQLite database and reach speeds closer to the consoleHost.exe test speeds. Are there better ways for creating the Channel/proxy? I've been reading about memory caching but I am not familiar with this and it would only make sense if this can be done global/ over different processes. All apps/service are always done locally on the same machine.

Comment: there is no alternative to establish the channel. 
Please check if you always close your DB connection if you use Ado.Db access. In case of EF you must use Async calls in all your data retrieval methods in worth case you run into a trouble with connection pull. A not proper handled data retrieval will lead to a performance gap and in case of an "aggressive" scenario - connection timeouts
my suggestions: mock the data access. check the performance by all consumers. If it solves the problem, go deeper with mocking until you find a problematic place.

Comment: I've reduced the service to a predefined list<> of 4 elements. All database methods are removed. I get following testresults for channelcreation:
(C = consolehost; 
A = app; 
P = plugin)

C1: 21ms   
C2: 6ms   
A1: 29ms   
A2: 6ms   
P1: 784ms   
P2: 1ms   

Note: I've done a first and second run per program. Total time of consolehost and app are more in line, but I can't see what would cause the plugin to be so much slower first call, are there any more security configurations to be done?

Comment: * total time in ms for the above 5 lines of code

Comment: I cannot tell you why the plugin takes so long to start for a first time. the question is much wider, than the one you initially asked ;) But the original question has been answered and already had been checked by you. After the Channel is created the average access speed is approximately the same. From the other hand first data access from the plugin is smaller than 1 sec. It is not that bad (especially for the plugin, where everything works over wrappers, reflection and so far)

Comment: if you want to give the user an illusion that there is no difference between very first and further service calls you can make a service call right away after plugin initialization. It can be a dummy data request, or you can implement a dummy "Ping" method by your service that does nothing. You can also use the Ping mehtod periodically (for example 1 per minute) to implement a "Heartbeat" to keep the Service Connection alive

Comment: The problem is the plugin in the external program reinitializes everytime it modifies or creates an object, so it can't be kept alive imo, thanks for the suggestions though :). That's also why first call is such a pain for me at 900ms. If I could on the other hand have similar speeds of 30ms first call as the ´app.exe´ that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigating: the external program prevented the sharing of loaded assemblies/JIT compilations through a setting in a .ini file when the process is started. Fortunately this could be disabled so sharing also becomes possible in the plugin.

After altering this setting (1 line in the .ini to No instead of Yes!) the time reduced to 30ms and every next call 3ms or less.